# SQL Server change real column to float without dropping index

Tags: sql-server

From what I have read and tested it is possible to alter the column type without dropping the index if we are just altering the size of the column.

For example if we update `varchar(50)` to `varchar(60)` then the alter statement will succeed without complaining.

But SQL Server did not like it when I tried to alter a `real` column to `float` without dropping the index first.

From the documentation

> The ISO synonym for real is float(24)

Which means I'm just increasing the size from 24 to 53. Is there a way to do this without having to recreate all the indexes?

Comment: What's the intention or overall goal? Pretty sure such a change locks the table anyway and thus you might as well drop the index, make the change and then recreate the index...

Comment: Doubtful, even though the underlying type is synonymous with the standard type the engine is going to treat it as a different type.

Comment: @FrankV live server, don't want to take it down. recreating all the index might take 10 min

Comment: Your index will have to be rebuilt because you've increased the size of the column, which will increase how much space each row takes up, which affects how many rows will fit on a page, etc.

Comment: @WesH not really. you can increase the size of varchar and numeric columns without rebuilding index. haven't tested others.